Python matrices in GF(2)
I want to manipulate matrices of elements of the finite field GF(2), where every element is a 1 or a 0, in Python. I see that numpy can use dtype=bool, but it uses saturating addition, not wrapping, so it doesn't implement GF(2) where 1 + 1 = 0. Is there a way to do this in numpy, or another package? I especially need to be able to do matrix multiplication, inversion, and solve systems of linear equations within the field.

I found the Galois library to do this:
import galois
GF2 = galois.GF(2)
x = GF2([[0, 0], [1, 1]])
y = GF2([[0, 1], [1, 0]])
x @ y

Gives the correct answer,
GF([[0, 0],
    [1, 1]], order=2)


If you want to use the numpy package you can achieve your 'wrapping' addition by using the xor operation. for example -
import numpy
x = numpy.array([[0,0],[1,1]])
y = numpy.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
x ^ y

gives an output of
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])

Which seems to match your needs

That's equivalent to addition in GF(2), not matrix multiplication.
